# How to build Classifiers which is used in creating the models?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I was going through the tutorial of speech emotion recognition and in between saw an "MLPClassifier(Multilayer_perceptron)" which was imported from the sklearn. And there are lots of other like Random forest and linear Regression, standardscalar,  GridSearchCV, etc. I was searching for tutorials or steps to how can I create these types of classifiers or modules on my own?

When I searched regarding these, I was getting examples of tutorials of the use cases of predefined classifiers of sklearn and third party claassifiers. Like above specified.

If you guys know any tutorial or steps to achieve these please suggest to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fro MLP, The implementation is quite easy, there is good explanation on how to implement on the [Coursera's ML introdcution](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning?utm_source=gg&utm_medium=sem&utm_content=07-StanfordML-ROW&campaignid=2070742271&adgroupid=80109820241&device=c&keyword=machine%20learning%20mooc&matchtype=b&network=g&devicemodel=&adpostion=1t1&creativeid=369041663186&hide_mobile_promo&gclid=CjwKCAiA3uDwBRBFEiwA1VsajFSKqThcKX8PqEElUinPkZ3xU_gMzWyR0XSIJjmc0D47SKTM23xKIRoCoOMQAvD_BwE) look to week 4 and week 5, for Linear and logistic regression look to week 2 and week 3. Look at this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/decision-tree-from-scratch-in-python-46e99dfea775) for implementing CART, random forests are quite similar I think you can figure out how to implement them easily if you are able to implement CART. For SVM and kernel methods you can look to this [repo](https://github.com/omarfoq/Kernel_Methods_for_Machine_Learning)

Comment: Thank you for reponse but I don't want to know about creating specifics like MLP, Random forest. I just want to know about the steps and smart way to create such types of classifiers.

Comment: Okey, basically you can sk-learn with is a great library under python that enables you to use all those methods. If you want to know more about what happening inside, I think that you can start reading two reference books: Introduction to statistical learning and Elements of statistical learning.  Not to forget the links I mentioned  in the answer

Comment: You still didn't get what I am asking. I am currently using sklearn library and from that MLP classifier and all. I know what is going on inside those classifiers. What I am asking is how to create those classifiers provided by sklearn on my own in a smart way.

Comment: Yeah, those are the link I sent in the first answer. They are providing steps for the construction of MLP classifier, CART trees, and SVM

Comment: Isn't there any general steps to create all type of classifiers not just specific ones.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no "general receipe" to create all type of classifiers, however you have some families of classifiers, e.g. Trees, SVM, neural nets, and for each family of them there is an idea that is common .

Comment: Can you please explain the implementation of other classification algorithms as well, like DecisionTree and RandomForest?
Also, I would like to know how to calculate the distance in case of multiple features/independent variables?

Comment: I have already put a [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/decision-tree-from-scratch-in-python-46e99dfea775) for decision trees, I would also recommand that you read the chapter on decision trees and the chapter on randomforest in [Introcustion to Statistical learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf). The second question on how to calculate distance is not precise, but as a general answer, you can use euclidean distance or cosine similarity.